# MySQL Query using NOT in it, possible?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of order status' and I'd like to return the amount of rows for which the value of that row is anything but Complete.

How would I go about this? I have the following which shows how much rows has 'New' as the status for the order. But I'd like to show all rows except ones with the od_status of Complete.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT od_status FROM tbl_order WHERE od_status = 'New'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows";
?>
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT od_status FROM tbl_order WHERE od_status != 'Complete'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT od_status FROM tbl_order WHERE od_status <> 'Complete'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_order WHERE od_status != 'Complete'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($result);
```

COUNT to count rows and != to select where is not equal to Complete.